# Jsr303 Bean Validation error message without prefix of form and field name

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6, bean-validation

I'm using bean validation and extval validation. 
I've created a properties file called `ValidationMessages.properties` inside my class path. inside this file i customized the defult messages ,

for example:
`javax.validation.constraints.Size.message=this is a test messgae`

when the fieild is being validated I can see the message I worte, but the problem is that I also see the field and form name before the message ' like this: `formName:fieldName this is a test`.
I want to remove this prefix. when it's a jsf validation I know that i need to add `javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE` property, but here it does not work.

what do I need to do inorder to remove this prefix and to see only the message itself?

**UPDATE:**
How can I override **both** bean validation and jsf default error messages? (and also to delete the prefix of the form and filed name befor the message)
I have `ValidationMessages.properties` for the bean messages and `messages.properties` for the jsf validation. what do I need to define inside the `config-xml` and the `web.xml` files? and where do I put the `javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE` property?

this is very very important to me,

any help will be appriciated,

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In which file did you specify the `javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE` property?

The property must be defined in a resource bundle known to JSF (e.g. a bundle registered in `faces-config.xml`), not within `ValidationMessages.properties`.

The property value must be `{0}` (`javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE={0}`) if you don't want to display the component labels, but the constraint violation message only. More information can be find in the JSF 2 spec, section 3.5.6.3.

Comment: actually you should not specify the property place holder {0}. If you do then it will show the client id. If the component has a label then {0} is overridden by the label name.

Comment: According to the JSF 2 spec it's not that way. It says in section 3.5.6.3: "... [JSF] should accept the interpolated message returned from Bean Validation API [...] and use it as the replacement value for the first numbered placeholder for the key `javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE` (i.e., `{0}`). [...] The developer may choose to override this message key in an application resource bundle and reference the component label, which replaces the second numbered placeholder (i.e., `{1}`)." So if you only want to have the BV message but not the label you should use the placeholder `{0}`.

Comment: @Gunnar: I added `javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE` property inside `messages.properties` file which I declared in the `faces-config` file like this: `<application><resource-bundle><base-name>messages</base-name><var>message</var></resource-bundle></application>` but now I can't see my custom messages for the jsf validation... I see the defult ones even though I have their properties inside `messages.properties` file. why is that??

Comment: @Gunnar:I have to properties files-`ValidationMessages` for the bean validation,and `messages` for the jsf validation.I want both of these file to override the defult messages for each validation type.how should I define them in the faces-config? when I define `messsages` inside a resource bundle,I can see ValidationMessages without the prefix,but then I don't see `messages` at all,it looks like it didn't override the defult messages.if I use message-bundle,I see the `messages` but then I see the `ValidationMessages` with the prefix!It's like one is overriding the other.how can I solve this???

Answer (score 0):

I think now you have solved this thing if not try this :-
in your .xhtml page means where you declare the component, make the lable attribute to blank(""). This will not take the prefix value,only the error message will display.

For a input text field you want some validation then use like this

```
<h:inputText id="abc" value="My Textbox" label="">
```

just try out with this, I think your problem may got resolve.